# Large import InnoDB - Error log entry analysis

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm currently import a large CSV file and I'm trying to understand the logs that are coming into my error.log file. The import keeps on going, so this might be nothing, but given that it's logged into the error.log file with a default set-up, and I have no idea what to make out of it, it might be time for me to learn something by reaching out to the MariaDB community.

The log I'm getting is the following:

```
=====================================
2021-09-30 21:03:22 0x7f0848d41640 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 20 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 564 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 1068 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 1632
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 309014
--Thread 139674486203968 has waited at trx0undo.cc line 777 for 436.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x56464c440288, Mutex REDO_RSEG created trx0rseg.cc:397, lock var 2

--Thread 139673591895616 has waited at buf0flu.cc line 1214 for 431.00 seconds the semaphore:
SX-lock on RW-latch at 0x7f085fda1ab0 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1563
a writer (thread id 139673460528704) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time write locked in file trx0rseg.ic line 43
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 1296199
RW-shared spins 1239237, rounds 9381718, OS waits 207220
RW-excl spins 865910, rounds 6692891, OS waits 88463
RW-sx spins 375, rounds 11083, OS waits 365
Spin rounds per wait: 7.57 RW-shared, 7.73 RW-excl, 29.55 RW-sx
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 429
Purge done for trx's n:o < 425 undo n:o < 87636886 state: running
History list length 1
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 428, ACTIVE 1482 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
1 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 51774178
MySQL thread id 48, OS thread handle 139674486203968, query id 78 localhost root Reading file
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE TABLE_X
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 1
452318 OS file reads, 589584 OS file writes, 172513 OS fsyncs
66.75 reads/s, 16384 avg bytes/read, 134.49 writes/s, 134.49 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 0 merges
merged operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 104 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
0.00 hash searches/s, 0.00 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 237726885168
Log flushed up to   237726880386
Pages flushed up to 237724062470
Last checkpoint at  237724062470
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
3473 log i/o's done, 0.95 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 405471232
Dictionary memory allocated 24640
Buffer pool size   8192
Free buffers       0
Database pages     8088
Old database pages 3003
Modified db pages  3448
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 42.626
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 2, single page 1
Pages made young 1119, not young 211124188
0.00 youngs/s, 200.24 non-youngs/s
Pages read 452305, created 195449, written 499116
66.75 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 66.75 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 900 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 298 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 8088, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[27390]:cur[946], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=37451, Main thread ID=139673583502912, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 51774178, updated 0, deleted 0, read 0
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 0, updated 0, deleted 0, read 0
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

I believe this is an output due to something timing out, but I have no idea as to what "that" could be. The import doesn't stop either, it just continues on. Any help (or pointers) on dissecting this log would be greatly appreciated!